# Zend Studio 7.0 + Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

I have used Zend Studio 7.0 on a project, and i don't know why is showing me something like this on my project http://screencast.com/t/fjBwsIUP

Answer (score 1):

It's the placeholder project that loads upon installation via Zend_Tool. Look inside application/views/scripts to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah found it on /scripts/index/index.phtml